# Python how to load an object stored inside a simple cookie by python

Tags: python, cookies

HI i have made a code to store the current user in a simple cookie made by python

```
    user_cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    user_cookie['current_user'] = pickle.dumps(profile_user)
    user_cookie['current_user']['max-age'] = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    logging.info(user_cookie['current_user'])
```

and i want to retrieve the object which i stored inside the cookie and access its elements from another handler and this is what I have done.

```
        user_cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        cookie_string = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
        if cookie_string is not None:
            user_cookie.load(cookie_string)

            logging.info(user_cookie['current_user'].user_name)


            cookie_user = pickle.loads(user_cookie['current_user'])
        if cookie_user is not None:

            logging.info(cookie_user.user_name)
```

It gives an error  . Can any one tell me how to get this thing done?

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: May be your pickled info exceeded the maximum value of 4096 characters?